# What output on this code means?

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe

I'm using [this tutorial](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/01-learning-lenet.ipynb) as example to build my caffe custom training function. On section 15 there is the following code:

```
def train():
    niter = 200
    test_interval = 25 
    train_loss = zeros(niter)
    test_acc = zeros(int(np.ceil(niter / test_interval)))

    ### HERE ###
    output = zeros((niter, 8, 10))
    ###      ###
```

On line 8 there is an `ndarray` (output), what is the meaning of this code and it demensions. What is the meaning of `(niter, 8, 10)`. Why `niter`, why 8 and why 10? Should I change this array according to my own data set? If yes, what dimension should I use? Can someone explain me it?

Comment: Please fix your code styling esp. indentation and provide a minimal working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read closely the tutorial you'll see that it deals with digits classification, hence the **10** classes. Moreover, they use a trick to tile 8 examples together (Section 11, near the `In [11]:`):

> # we use a little trick to tile the first eight images

Hence the **8** dimension.

Section 15 shows an example of tracking the progress of the network. It saves the output prediction probability per iteration. There are **10** classes times **8** examples per iteration, and there are **`niter`** iterations to track. All this information is stored in the 3D `output` array.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a call to [`numpy.zeros`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) where `shape = (niter, 8, 10)` which creates a 200 * 8 * 10 array of float 0.

Comment: Yeah, I understand it. What I do not know why, is why this ndarray has this dimension? Should I change it according to my own data set?